# Is there a gulp watch alternative that compiles sass only when the scss file is saved?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm looking for an alternative to the 'gulp watch' task that compiles scss only when I save the scss file. Is there any?

I'm asking this because when gulp watch is 'kept alive' in my prompt, it incredibily slows down my computer when i start to modify things in my scss file.

Sorry if this is a noob question but I'm new to Gulp!

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//style paths
var sassFiles = 'sass/**/*.scss',  
    cssDest = 'css/';

gulp.task('styles', function(){  
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('watch',function() {  
    gulp.watch(sassFiles,['styles']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, **all** scss files are compiled every time **one** file is changed. This might slow things down.

If you want to compile only the changed scss file, you'll need to do it like this.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {  
    gulp.watch(sassFiles, function(obj) {
        return gulp.src(obj.path)
           .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
    });
});
```